# multiple images per node

Tags: nodes, media

I have a client who has a portfolio type site which requires a custom content type and the requirement to attach multiple images to each record.

Imagefield allows a fixed number of images, but I am curious if there are better solutions for implementing a photo gallery?

I suppose I could add another content type called "gallery" and associate it to "portfolio" but this seems excessive and way to much work for my client to add/remove images to a potfolio...ideas???

Comment: if the only requirement is that your client is able to attach multiple to a unique record (node?) than I think that's the most logical way to go for. I don't understand why you would want to attach a content type Gallery to a content type portfolio. Or is portfolio just a path?

Comment: Whenever I've allowed a node that is image-like in a client's mind to have cardinality I've regretted it later. I'd lean toward keeping a 1-1 on imagefield-to-node and handle cardinality via taxonomy or entity reference which serve to create virtual folders or portfolios. Entity reference prepopulate works well in this scenario.

Comment: I need the number of images to be arbitrary...some projects have 3 photos - others have dozens